# Webview with self-signed certificate

Tags: android-webview

Can anybody  confirm success with connecting android webview via https, using p12 for authentication? I need to load my website from https://mysite.com into a webview, but no success. With web service I used SSLContext to create and initiate keystore to authentiate to server successfully. But from webview I dont know how to authentiate. I tried the following solutions: [android webview with client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588851/android-webview-with-client-certificate/15590041#15590041). but still unsuccessfull