# Certificate Pinning in Android Webview

Tags: android, ssl, webview, ssl-certificate, certificate-pinning

I am creating a small demo app to implement ssl certificate pinning in android webview. I have generated the certificates of the host.
Can anyone suggest me how to pin the certificates in the application code.
I have searched many links but I am still stuck.

Comment: The question is a little old now. Were you able to get through? Or still looking for an answer?

Answer (score -1):

WebViews are tricky, not least because there is no perfect way to implement pinning in them except with Android N using [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CertificatePinning).

The best you can do is override `shouldInterceptRequest` and implement the network calls yourself using one of the methods described in [Android Security: SSL Pinning](https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e), however this only intercepts GET requests so if your WebViews use POST requests then you are out of luck. [Android-SSL-Pinning-WebViews](https://github.com/menjoo/Android-SSL-Pinning-WebViews/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mennomorsink/webview/SecureWebViewClient.kt) shows an example of doing this.

Comment: Android-SSL-Pinning-WebViews Link is broken

Comment: How about using onReceivedClientCertRequest and attaching certificates for cert pinning? 
Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35403556/6641282

Comment: I believe that is in place for the server to request certificates from the client, so unless your server asks for one `onReceivedClientCertRequest` won’t even be called