# Python :ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100

Tags: python, ssl

I find a previously working script on my computer B unable to work on my computer A

I want to use this package tvdatafeed to get data from tradingview
https://pypi.org/project/tvdatafeed/
After installed it via **pip**

```
pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/StreamAlpha/tvdatafeed.git
```

And write a manual login initialization script (https://github.com/StreamAlpha/tvdatafeed seen under **usage**)

```
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed,Interval
tv = TvDatafeed(auto_login=False)
```

The terminal report **error**

```
You need to login manually

 Press 'enter' to open the browser

opening browser. Press enter once lgged in return back and press 'enter'. 

DO NOT CLOSE THE BROWSER

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5084/devtools/browser/1517b9bc-9537-4189-badc-e2848a692c66
[21180:14016:1213/013224.084:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[21180:14016:1213/013225.282:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[21180:14016:1213/013229.627:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[6392:6044:1213/013229.737:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(226)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[6392:6044:1213/013229.737:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(229)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[6392:6044:1213/013229.738:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(232)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[6392:6044:1213/013229.754:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
[6392:12584:1213/013229.773:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [01:32:29.773] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting Default Adapter failed.[21180:14016:1213/013237.335:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[21180:14016:1213/013241.403:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(983)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

My question is: does this SSL error has something related to me using a SSR proxy (SSL5)? If so how do i let the program to know it?

I found two similar issues regarding the SSL error ([handshake failed; returned -1, ssl error code 1, net_error -202](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442126/handshake-failed-returned-1-ssl-error-code-1-net-error-202)

[Selenium ssl_client_socket_impl.cc handshake failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65755603/selenium-ssl-client-socket-impl-cc-handshake-failed/65906969)).
Solutions in those two issues relate to ignoring certificate error. But in my case, I don't have a handle to the webdriver. So how do I fix that?

Thanks in advance..