# How to open https:localhost for testing inside WebView app in emulator as getting ssl handshake issue

Tags: android, ssl, webview

I am working on a website which will open inside WebView of android app. I wanted to test my website in emulator during development but since my website having https://localhost:3000, Emulator WebView App is unable to open it. Given error **[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202**.

Please help to open https://localhost:3000 inside emulator's WebView tester app.

Comment: Servers are not magically accessible with HTTPS  by just changing the `http://` in the URL to `https://`. The server needs to specifically setup to support HTTPS and nothing in your question indicates that this was done.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - My website is ssl enabled and hosted on a secure domain. while running a local instance, it's open on https: //localhost:3000. One page of this website need to be open inside android WebView. 
For development testing i just wanted to open https: //localhost:3000 through webView tester app but no luck as getting handshake error.  Hope this answer to your question. Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: *"while running a local instance, it's open on https: //localhost:3000"* - are you sure (and can you prove it)?The error message suggests, that it doesn't. My guess is that the external site is SSL enabled but then uses some reverse proxy to forward to `http://localhost:3000`, i.e. `http://` not `https://`. That's at least what the common setups are doing.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Yes! i am sure. https: //localhost:3000 is running on browser with SSL warning. but not unable to run on WebView , this what the error is.

Comment: Check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442126/handshake-failed-returned-1-ssl-error-code-1-net-error-202 solves your problem. Looks like same error message in same use case (webview)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - These solution is to fix on android code site. i don't have control over android app (using pre build app called WebView tester just to check local env.).  I need something either to do on emulator setting or in website.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all create one common network: the best way is to share `personal hotspot` from your mobile phone.
- After that you need to connect this `personal hotspot` from your emulator computer and local server computer. If you have one computer for both of them, that's ok.
- Then you should get the `IP address` of the local server and in android method `loadUrl` add this `IP:port`. Example `webView.loadUrl("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/myPath")`