Getting handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 Error in Android Studio
I'm making an Android App using Capacitor/android from a Web Angular App, the Web-App is working fine but when I'm running the App in Android it's giving the below Error
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
File: https://localhost/vendor.js - Line 263078 - Msg: gmsServices_Authentication: login()  http reply error:  status: 0; statusText: Unknown Error
[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(879)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202


I have added the following code to my AndroidManifect.xml file too -
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
The above code is returning me a warning that Attribute usesCleartextTrafficis only used in API level 23 and higher (current min is 22)
What can I do to solve this?

@Robert I'm using a Virtual Device on Android Studio (Pixel 8 API 33) and also tried on physical devices with Android 11 but its still showing "No Connection" on the login Window in the Android App.

https://localhost can not have a valid certificate. How have you trusted the server certificate?

Is this the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442126/handshake-failed-returned-1-ssl-error-code-1-net-error-202

@rand'Chris Probably, the same error but I don't know much about that as I'm new to Angular and Android, right now I can't seem to understand what the Android WebView is doing there.  Maybe the error is same but the context is different. I don't know, but thankyou for the suggestion, I'll look more into that.

@Robert
I tried to implement the following code in this

<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors><certificates src="system" /><certificates src="user" /></trust-anchors></base-config>


But still the app is not working on the Android. I took reference from this https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config#recommendations-link
If you use https then the cleartext traffic entry is useless. And your server uses localhost which means it can not have a valid certificate. This means you have to add you https certificate as debug certificate to your app as described by Google. https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config#TrustingDebugCa BTW: Please don't post code like XML code in comments. Edit your question instead and add it, properly formatted, there.

@Robert My server is using HTTP that's why I have added the clearTextTraffic entry, but its not helping. And I'll keep in my to edit the code in the question from next time on, Sorry for that, and Thank you for the suggestions.

The error message clearly states that you are using HTTPS: https://localhost/vendor.js.

That's the problem, I don't want to use https but its still showing me that, I don't know how to change that, my server don't use https. The Web App is working just fine, I don't what's the issue with Android App. And I think as you can guess I'm a beginner in this field, I can't seem to understand the problem correctly.
