# Android WebView "handshake failed" issue on onReceivedClientCertRequest

Tags: android, ssl, webview, keystore, client-certificates

We are developing an Android application where we embed our launchpad URL into a webview object. The problem is that we are keep getting below error whenever we try to sign in.

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(959)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
```

We referred to the solution under [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135225/android-webview-handle-onreceivedclientcertrequest) but for security purposes, our IT team is reluctant to share the private key, leading me to seek alternative solutions that do not necessitate its use. Despite exploring various options, I continually encounter approaches that require the private key.

Is there a feasible method to bypass this issue without the need of a private key? Or, alternatively, are there secure ways which our IT team might be able to share the private key?

Below solution applied but doesnt work without private key:

```
           @Override  
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {  
                handler.proceed();  
            }  
  
            @Override  
            public void onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, final ClientCertRequest request) {  
                if (mCertificates == null || mPrivateKey == null) {  
                    loadCertificateAndPrivateKey();  
                }  
                request.proceed(mPrivateKey, mCertificates);  
            }
```

```
   private void loadCertificateAndPrivateKey() {
        try {
            InputStream fis = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/keystore.bks");
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            String password = "password";
            keyStore.load(fis, password != null ? password.toCharArray() : null);

            InputStream certificateFileStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/RootCA.crt");
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate certGenerated = cf.generateCertificate(certificateFileStream);

            // Close the certificate stream
            if (certificateFileStream != null) {
                certificateFileStream.close();
            }

            // Add the certificate to the keystore
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("RootCA", certGenerated);

            Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
            String alias = aliases.nextElement();

            **// Here key object returns null, as understandably since no private key is imported.**
            Key key = keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
            if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
                mPrivateKey = (PrivateKey)key;
                Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
                mCertificates = new X509Certificate[1];
                mCertificates[0] = (X509Certificate)cert;
            }

            certificateFileStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Merve