# android onReceivedSslError

Tags: android, security

I encounter this problem

[image]

I tried to resolve by two ways. First, I refer to this
[Webview avoid security alert from google play upon implementation of onReceivedSslError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050741/webview-avoid-security-alert-from-google-play-upon-implementation-of-onreceiveds). Second, I remove the implement of onReceivedSslError

Google still rejected

Anyone has right way for me? thank you!

Comment: you have to upload your security certificated to verify that you are the owner of particular web content that you are displaying in your website.

or else open url in external web browser.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded my cert for that server and I was using https://. I used webview to display that web, but google still rejected

Comment: you have to install that certificate in application mean to say in apk file.

Comment: How to install please!?

Comment: chechout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720753/android-google-play-warning-ssl-error-handler-vulnerability)

Comment: I resolve it by this way, but Google still rejected
https://s27.postimg.org/69ryemb8j/Screen_Shot_2017_01_19_at_17_53_27.png

Comment: was I wrong keyur9779 ? https://s27.postimg.org/69ryemb8j/Screen_Shot_2017_01_19_at_17_53_27.png