# Why does Security Alert still show after APK upgrade in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-security

I received the following security alert in my Google Play Console.

> Security alert
>
> Your app is using an unsafe implementation of
> WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. Please see this Google Help
> Centre article for details, including the deadline for fixing the
> vulnerability.
>
> Affects APK version 10.

So, I have removed this implementation and have rolled out a new APK version 13. There doesn't seem to be any problem for the new version but the Security Alert still continues to show for APK version 10. I thought removing the specified implementation and upgrading the APK would fix this but that doesn't seem to be the case as I didn't receive any message or alert saying it has been fixed. So am I supposed to delete APK version 10 from the console or is there any way to resolve this step by step?

Comment: Probably what you are searching is here and answered <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720753/android-google-play-warning-ssl-error-handler-vulnerability>?

Comment: @pradhu hi, thanks for the reference but I have already removed the implementation as I have stated above so the new APK version 13 doesn't have this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for a couple of hours and going back to my console, I noticed that the alert is dismissed. So I think the problem had been resolved but that I just had to wait.