# WebView SSL Error Handler - Android Google Play Warning

Tags: android, ssl, android-webview

When I submit a version to Google Play, it is constantly rejected due to SSL and the incoming mail says **"For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article."** I'm getting the message.
I tried many methods. I removed the **onReceivedSslError()** method and it didn't work. I used **cancel()** method instead of **proceed()** and it still didn't work. Finally, I tried the solution in the link below, it still did not work.

[android Google Play Warning: SSL Error Handler Vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720753/android-google-play-warning-ssl-error-handler-vulnerability)

I have sent versions about 5-6 times. Now I want to submit a version with a guaranteed solution, but I couldn't find enough documentation.

**Error email sent to me**

**SSL Error Handler**
For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this Google Help Center article.

How can I submit my app to Google Play Store without getting stuck with this error?

Comment: Hello there , have you find a solution.