# Fingerprint authentication in Android app wrapping a web page

Tags: android, authentication, html, fingerprint

I have a webpage that needs authentication which can be tedious to enter on mobile so I was thinking of creating a wrapper application that could login the user (only one - me) automatically with saved credentials. In order to protect the credentials I want to use the fingerprint API (I use a Samsung S5). However this is new stuff for me so I have few questions about the feasibility:

- Is it possible to automatically log into a web page from an app wrapper?
- Could this work with a non-trusted certificate (I have to generate my own)
- Can I encrypt and use the fingerprint to decrypt the credentials so they are secure on the phone?

Answer (score 2):

### Is it possible to automatically log into a web page from an app wrapper?

yes

### Could this work with a non-trusted certificate (I have to generate my own)

No in general, if you are meaning HTTPS certificate. but [android webview with client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588851/android-webview-with-client-certificate) may help

### Can I encrypt and use the fingerprint to decrypt the credentials so they are secure on the phone?

Yes. in pratice refer to http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/10/new-in-android-samples-authenticating.html