# How to make webview show a certificate dialog?

Tags: android, webview, certificate, client-certificates

I did an App for our company which allows the user open some company sites like calendars, emails and such stuff in a build-in WebView.

Now, they changed the way of getting into the email-box.
The user needs a certificate, which is not a problem in chrome to choose.

But how can I get this working in my WebView?
Has anybody a clue how to do that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android webview with client certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588851/android-webview-with-client-certificate) In general it is not possible. Read  the link