# specific website link not opening in webview

Tags: java, android

Well as the title states I tried to open a link from onCreate and onpostexecute via webview, configured it properly as it opens all other webpages both with http and https as well as aspx and php, except the one i need, below is the code, please help!

```
try{
                mWebView = (WebView)
                        findViewById(R.id.WebView2);
               //mWebView.loadUrl("https://excise.wb.gov.in/Default.aspx");
                mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
                String url = "https://excise.wb.gov.in/Default.aspx";
                mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
 private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I know string url is deprecated but i tried the new param also, it did not yield any fruit either, furthermore the dep. method is working fine with other url.

Answer (score 0):

The site maybe has bad ssl certificate or some JS errors.
The site was unavailable when I have oppened it and returns 503 errors.

Take a look on answers into this link 
android-webview-with-client-certificate][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588851/android-webview-with-client-certificate)

Comment: the site is up now, yet the problem persists.

Comment: public void onReceivedSslError works, but I am worried about whether google would allow this.