# When I use client certificate in android app, should I store private storage ? Is it common way?

Tags: android, certificate, storage, pkcs#12

We're developing android app that has native `login form(intent)` and `WebView`.
We require user to get client certificate from `api` before login, and use it when user login(api).
And I plan to store the certificate that user install as `PKCS12` file in private storage of app.

Now, I have to survey the way I said above is in common.
Please give your opinion and if you don't agree and have another idea, teach me.
thank you.

Comment: You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588851/android-webview-with-client-certificate

Comment: this discussion says "try to use keychain?"

Comment: At this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) ,its for using when store private keys or 
directory of cert storage. I think when using SSL connetion I need to get stream from file. And android developer site doesn't indicate where should we keep certificate file. that' why I want know people keep that file where in common. If you, where you store certfile?